# Encapsulation in C functions - K&R section 1.9

Tags: c, function

I am fairly new to C, and I am working through Ritchie's and Kernighan's The C programming language, and I don't understand how the following code works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

int getline(char line[], int maxline);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

int main()
{
    int len;
    int max;
    char line[MAXLINE];
    char longest[MAXLINE];

    max = 0;
    while((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
        if (len > max) {
            max = len;
            copy(longest, line);
        }
    if (max > 0)
        printf("%s", longest);
    return(0);
}

int getline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;

    for (i=0; i<lim-1 && (c = getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return(i);
}

void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
}
```

What I don't get is how does the copy function affect anything without returning anything, I am used to Python where functions can only affect outwith themselves through return values, and I was under the impression C was the same.
I have tested the code and it does work.

Comment: It modifies `to` and `from`. Inside `copy()`, `to` and `from` are pointer types, so you are writing to memory that the caller has access to (so its actions are visible by the caller)

Comment: You're making the mistake of thinking C has strings as primitive types like other languages. It doesn't: in C, when you pass a "string" to a function, what you're really passing is the memory address at which it starts, allowing that function to write all over memory at that address and subsequent ones (if it's in writable memory).

Comment: in the line `while((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')` **there is an assignment** (`to[i] = from[i]`)  There are people that implements copy as `while (*to++ = *from++);`  (look, the while block is actually empty, everything is solved in the test expression.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`void copy(char to[], char from[])` is actually the same like `void copy(char *to, char *from)`. So, two pointers are passed to the copy function. The function can change the destinations of the pointers. This mechanism is known as "call by reference".
(The copy function only needs to change the destination of the to-pointer, the destination of the from-pointer needs not to be changed. This can be made clearer with `void copy(char *to, const char *from)`.)

Answer (score 4):

The statement `while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')` is actually an assignment disguised within the comparison.

It's a shorthand code that I personally find confusing, and you're proving that it infact is.

Comment: Yes, the while loop is hard to read. Mabe this would be better to understand:
`do
{
    to[i] = from[i];
} while (to[i++]!='\0');
`
But there is also this post-increment, which is mixed with the comparison

Answer (score 2):

That `copy` function works through the magic of pointers.
In essence, pointers are basically a memory address that you can access like an array from the same program.

On a side note, [Learn C the Hard way](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/) is, in my opinion, a better book.
He explains many concepts of C, <strike>and he also points out some flaws in that very same `copy` function you are asking about</strike>.

**UPDATE**

He actually removed his section on K&R C, because he believes that C is dead.
I think he is wrong, but, to each his own.

Comment: That copy function doesn't use any pointers at all. Please, don't confuse array indexing with pointer dereferencing.  The original K&R code doesn't make any pointer arithmetic (it increments the array indexes, not the pointers)  Perhaps reading that book instead of K&R has made you have such a trouble not differencing pointers from arrays.

Comment: @LuisColorado I know the difference, but an array is a pointer to the stack rather than the heap. I can define a variable as an array and pass it to a function asking for a pointer and it works. In fact, I don't like defining parameters as being arrays, even if that is what I am passing.

Comment: sorry, but an array is not a pointer.  you can have arrays in the stack as well than in the heap as well as in the main data segment.  An array is an ordered, contiguous list of data elements, all of the same type and size, and a pointer is an address of data.  They are different things.  An array has a different `sizeof` value than a pointer.  This last thing might at least make you thing they are different.

Comment: @LuisColorado I will acknowledge that an array is a different type, but it is still a memory address, which is what I define as a pointer.